# making changes to a base64 string and saving it as an image

Tags: python, image-processing, base64

I'm converting an image to a base64 string in python, turning that into a list, making changes to a few characters and converting the base64 string back to an image.

The purpose of this is to create glitch art, where small changes in the image's encoding can produce certain effects.

This is what my code looks like:

```
import base64
import random
import string

times = 0
with open(r"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\image.jpg", "rb") as image:
    text = base64.b64encode(image.read())
text = str(text)
text = list(text)
char_no = len(text)
while True:
    crpt_amn = input("how much do you want to corrupt the image? insert a value from 0 to " + str(char_no) + " ")
    try:
      if int(crpt_amn) < 0:
          print("value is out of range!")
      elif int(crpt_amn) > char_no:
          print("value is out of range!")
      else:
          break          
    except ValueError:
          print("that isn't a number")
while times < (int(crpt_amn) + 1):
    picked = random.randint(0, char_no)
    if text[picked] == '/':
        times += 1
    else:
        text[picked] = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
        times += 1    
text = ''.join(text)
text = str.encode(text)
text = base64.b64decode(text)
filename = "out_img.jpg"
with open(filename, "wb") as picture:
    picture.write(text)
```

However, there seems to be an issue with converting `text` to `str(text)` to `str.encode(text)` and back to `base64.b64decode(text)` as the output image wouldn't open.

The changes made to the base64 string are minuscule, and even if you set `crypt_amn` to 0, such that no changes are made to it, the output image still wouldn't open.

I've tried getting rid of the whole corruption part and stripped down the code to just this:

```
import base64
import random
import string

with open(r"C:\Users\Justin\Desktop\image.jpg", "rb") as image:
    text = base64.b64encode(image.read())
text = str(text)
text = str.encode(text)
text = base64.b64decode(text)
filename = "out_img.jpg"
with open(filename, "wb") as picture:
    picture.write(text)
```

yet the output image is still unable to be opened.

Is there any way to achieve the desired functionality, with the user being able to make edits to the base64 string as a list?

Thank you!

*(sorry if I got some terminology wrong or my question seems absurd, I'm still a beginner at python)*

Comment: base64 can't be changed however you like when editing it... not only do you have to make sure only legal base64 characters are entered but you need to make sure the length stays the same because base64 works on 6/8 bits per byte so when the input increases by 1 character the output can increase by either 1 character or 2 characters... you really should just use  base16 its much more easy to translate to and from binary with it

Comment: As well as the issue of corrupting the base64 data that AntiMatterDynamite mentioned, there's the even bigger issue of corrupting the JPEG file structure. If you want to do random things to pixels you need to extract the pixel data from the image file, eg using PIL. Forget about the base64 stuff, you can just modify the raw RGB `bytes` data directly. Then pass it back to PIL to build a new JPEG.

Comment: In the mean time, I suggest you learn a little bit about Unicode encoding. Many years ago, Stack Overflow co-founder Joel Spolsky wrote a great article: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) which is still worth reading. Also see the Python [Unicode HowTo](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html).